# Setting java build commands in TextMate 2

Tags: java, classpath, text-editor, textmate

I'm looking to keep .java and .class files in different folders.

In Ubuntu, I could do this in Geany by:
Build > Set Build Commands >

Compile: javac -d ~/path/to/class/files "%f"
Execute: java -cp ~/path/to/class/files "%e"

Is there a similar solution in textmate 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextMate actually uses its own bundles.  You can see/install them from Preferences -> Bundles.  Here is a small article with more info if you need it: http://blog.likewise.org/2013/04/using-textmate-to-rapidly-test-java-code-examples-slash-sscces/

Comment: I just tried HelloWorld, but can't find the class file in the folder where the java file is located.

Comment: @SaurabhMishra Can you post your error? I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: I'm able to run the program without any errors. I just need to know where the .class file is located.

Comment: @SaurabhMishra  The class file to what exactly?

Comment: There's a file by the name HelloWorld.java in a directory (which I'm able to execute), however the HelloWorld.class file is not present there. Where is it located?

Comment: @SaurabhMishra TextMate (as I know) will not give you the compiled file anywhere.  TextMates "run" is for testing.  You will need to compile with something else. You can use the Terminal (if you know how) to navigate to the directory and run `javac HelloWorld.java` but this will be an executable. If you need help with compiling, you will either need to do some research or ask a new question. Class files are inside the compiled ".jar"